# pgSQL to overwrite one set of table rows with another based on ID

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table along the lines of -

```
set_id, id, ...
0, 1, a, b, ...
1, 1, c, d, ...
2, 1, e, f, ...
0, 2, g, h, ...
1, 2, i, j, ...
2, 2, k, l, ...
```

where (set_id, id) is a primary key

I would like to replace all fields except set_id for all entries with set_id 0 with the equivalent entry (if it exists) with set_id 1. So the table above would become -

```
set_id, id, ...
0, 1, c, d, ... <
1, 1, c, d, ...
2, 1, e, f, ...
0, 2, i, j, ... <
1, 2, i, j, ...
2, 2, k, l, ...
```

Is there a sane way to do this in SQL or do I need to use some client side code?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share a desired result in table form? I'm having a hard time understanding the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I'm reading correctly, you want to copy the data in the row with `set_id=1` to the row with `set_id=0` for each value of `id`.

One way of doing it is to do a simple `UPDATE` with a `FROM`;

```
UPDATE mytable
 SET field_a = ms.field_a, field_b = ms.field_b
FROM mytable ms
WHERE mytable.id=ms.id AND mytable.set_id=0 AND ms.set_id=1
```

Note that you need to list the fields you want moved, the "row copy" is not automatic for all fields.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/266cb/1).

Comment: Thanks - looks good. Shall test and accept if all go's well :)

Comment: Unfortunately, whilst this works with mysql it doesn't seem to with postgres :/

Comment: @user2036256 Oops, misread as MySQL however that happened. Updated for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks :) That was far simpler than I was expecting